# Installing VTK for Python 3 on Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-installation, python3

I am trying to install Mayavi on my desktop workstation, running Fedora 26. It's working fine in Python 2 (2.7.13) but not with Python 3 (3.6.2), where the installation fails because Python can't find the module `vtk`. I've installed all the packages I think I need (hence it works with Python 2). e.g.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i vtk
vtk-qt-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-python-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-qt-python-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-java-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-devel-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-tcl-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
vtk-qt-tcl-7.1.1-3.fc26.x86_64
```

But Python 3 can't see VTK, though Python 2 can.

```
$ python2 -c "import vtk"
$ python3 -c "import vtk"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'
```

Now, as far as I know, VTK didn't support Python 3 until the end of 2015/start of 2016. But I figure it's had a year to percolate through various systems...

I tried poking around in the installation files to see if I could find more information.  `find /usr/lib64/vtk/ | grep -i python` turned up a bunch of libraries with `Python27D` in the file names and I noticed a corresponding lack of anything with `Python3`. Similarly, there's a folder `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/` but nothing under `python3.5` or `python3.6`.

Is VTK not supported with Python 3 on Fedora (through the repositories, anyway)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is VTK not supported with Python 3 on Fedora (through the repositories, anyway)?

It looks like it is not packaged for Python3, as visible from the spec file:

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/vtk-python/sources/spec/

But it does not mean that it can not be fixed. All the python packages in Fedora should be built for both python 2 and 3 if possible so the least you can do is to fill a bug on vtk package, if you need a python 3 package. Better approach would be to submit also a patch, but it would require some knowledge about Fedora packaging (but it is a good thing to know anyway if you use Fedora).

Comment: Thanks for this. Following the link, it looks like the lack of Python3 package is a known issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1319504#c4